# Tomcat 7.0.28 is not starting

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to add a ZK project to the Tomcat 7 in Eclipse. But it fails.
Here is the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component      
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ERAZK]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1142)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1595)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1585)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  
   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ERAZK]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/DefaultPieDataset
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:108)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:279)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:141)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:382)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:346)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
   ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.data.DefaultPieDataset
  at  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    ... 21 more
```

I have checked my classpath and jfreechart.jar is in my WEB-INF folder. I saw similar errors with HttpServlet error here, but it did not help my problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: jfreechart should be in WEB-INF\lib directory, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have checked my classpath and jfreechart.jar is in my WEB-INF folder.
```

Add JFreeChart libraries in WEB-INF/lib and not in WEB-INF directory